# cfsearch - Error executing query : org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse : Lexical error

Tags: coldfusion, lucene, cfsearch

I've got a basic cfsearch that works fine, but occasionally it can be broken with search strings like the following;

- my search string]
- "my search string
- my search string[
- my search: string

Any of the above will result in an error like;

> Error executing query : org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse '"my search string': Lexical error at line 1, column 32. Encountered:  after : "\"my search string"

I was thinking I could strip out those characters, but you might have a working search term with, say, two "" - ie. "my search string" - which is valid.  Is there a preferable way to prepare a string for cfsearch?

So, in the example of:

> "my search string

it would strip out the first ".  But if the search term was:

> "my search string"

all good - leave it alone.  Any ideas?! Are there any other characters that can cause an error?  For example, a hacker tried this;

> XyOk,'.](.]]]'

Which caused an error.

Comment: In Lucence 4+ these are all special characters `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /` see http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters

Comment: thanks john, good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [VerityClean UDF](http://www.cflib.org/udf/verityClean) from [CFLib](http://cflib.org/) to sanitize the Verity/Lucene search parameter.  (NOTE: Add `:`, `^` and `*` to the pipe-delimited `reBadChars` variable so they will be stripped for Lucene.)

http://www.cflib.org/udf/verityClean